# Would decorated function calling another decorator function return normally?

Tags: python, decorator

How does the control flow work in case of decorators ?  Is there anyway I can modify calleedec and make it not return to caller after its getting invoked ? Its not my desired scenario I see a similar bug so wondering if thats possible ? **Isn't it just like normal functions ?**

Trying to debug an issue -  we hit the first pdb but not the second pdb as in the scenario below ?

Both are decorated functions .

```
@cooldec()
def caller():
    import pdb;pbd.set_trace()  # Hits here
    callee()
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace() # Not here

@calleedec()
def callee():
    return "Okay
```

Edit:

Raising Error is one scenario but no error trace .

I can see a case where callee's decorator in an infinite loop or is not able to do its job (taking long time) , this can happen .

Comment: You want `calee` to return and somehow jump out of its parent function as well?

Comment: Wondering if thats possible - I dont want to but I see a bug like that . I am assuming after calle is completed it has to return back .

Comment: I think it might be possible if you put a conditional based on the return value of `callee` directly after it returns that could also return from its caller, but it might be simpler to refactor somehow so that this is not necessary. It's quite confusing internal logic if anyone ever had to debug your decorators, for example.

Comment: I suppose `callee` could raise an exception.

Comment: Also its possible callee is an infinite loop right ?

Comment: For the gentleman who voted for closing this question , I would like to know what is confusing about this question to vote for closing ? Perhaps you don't get what I ask ?  Not everyone is any expert . And I have posted a code snippet explaining what I am trying to ask .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorated functions are just plain functions, and have nothing special to them regarding program flow.

When in doubt, try to expand the decorator and see if that is clearer:

```py
def calleedec(callee_fn):
    def wrapped():
        print("Running the callee")
        callee_fn()
    return wrapped

def callee():
    return "Okay"

callee = calleedec(callee)

def cooldec(fn):
    def wrapped():
        print("Running the caller")
        return fn()
    return wrapped

@cooldec
def caller():
    print("caller: start")
    callee()
    print("caller: end")

caller()

# Running the caller
# caller: start
# Running the callee
# caller: end
```

To avoid the callee hijacking the flow and not returning to the caller function you would need to do some serious black magic with the stack. So I don't think you should worry about this.

If you are not hitting the second pdb breakpoint, something may be happening in your callee function.